# Is there any ROS community effort bases on golang?

Tags: ros, programming-languages

I recently read a Go language(Golang) book and feel that this language is what I like.

I like C and Python, C can do the low level and basic jobs well. This language is also designed lovely. Also python(but python is really slow...). The Golang can also embed C. So may Golang also be good for Robot development in the future?

Is there any effort bases on golang in ROS community now? Any reason that Golang is not good for ROS/robotics?

Answer (score 1):

recently I find a project called "rosgo" which is doing similar thing. But seems that it is not active recently. here's thel link: [wiki.ros.org/rosgo](http://wiki.ros.org/rosgo)
Hope this project can go further because golang is designed well like c and alleviate the develop time problem of c/c++ && run speed problem of python.

Comment: If you're concerned with speed for python, then write C++ modules and use Python to call them, or use Cython to convert your Python to C.